# Python looping issue

Tags: python

I'm new to python so I am trying to create some simple programs to learn some more.

This program that I need help with is meant to perform the following steps:

- Ask for a name
- Ask for a number of times to repeat something in a song
- Print the given lyrics the given number of times

But I am having a problem with it not repeating, what am I doing wrong?

```
def bSong(name):
    print('Happy Birthday to you!')
    print("Happy birthday dear " + name + "")

def main():
    times = int(input('Enter the number of times to repeat: '))
    for i in range(times):
        name = input("What is the name of the birthday person: ")
        bSong(name)

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change:

```
def main():
    times = int(input('Enter the number of times to repeat: '))
    for i in range(times):
        name = input("What is the name of the birthday person: ")
        bSong(name)
```

to:

```
def main():
    times = int(input('Enter the number of times to repeat: '))
    name = input("What is the name of the birthday person: ")
    for i in range(times):
        bSong(name)
```

As it stands you're asking the user to input the name multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the name input outside the loop like this:

```
def bSong(name):
    print('Happy Birthday to you!')
    print("Happy birthday dear " + name + "")

def main():
    name = input("What is the name of the birthday person: ")
    times = int(input('Enter the number of times to repeat: '))
    for i in range(times):
        bSong(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

put `name = input("What is the name of the birthday person: ")` outside of the for loop, if you want to read the name once.

```
def bSong(name):
    print('Happy Birthday to you!')
    print("Happy birthday dear " + name + "")

def main():
    times = int(input('Enter the number of times to repeat: '))
    name = input("What is the name of the birthday person: ")
    for i in range(times):
        bSong(name)




main()
```

Is that what you are expecting or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves your problem in python 2.7

```
def bSong(name):
    print('Happy Birthday to you!') 
    print("Happy birthday dear " + name + "")
def main(): 
    times = int(input('Enter the number of times to repeat: ')) 
    for i in range(times): 
        name = raw_input("What is the name of the birthday person: ")
        bSong(name)
main()
```